# Jquery .fadeToggle() works on one page, doesn't on another (same code)

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, firebug

Using Jquery (1.7.1) I am trying to make an image .fadeToggle on .hover()

The image is at the top of the page, it says "Concurso de Desfraces...."

The code works on this page: https://tienda.lirainwonderland.es

**Why does it not work on this page?**: http://lirainwonderland.es

I am able to make an alert work on .hover() so I am sure the problem is with .fadeToggle()

I have tried used firebug to find the source of this issue and there does seem to be a diference on the Stack tab of the Scripts panel when I break the script on line, not sure why though...

Here is the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("#concurso").hover(function () { 
   $('#concurso2').fadeToggle("slow", "linear");            
});
});
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#concurso {
 position: relative;
}

#concurso2 {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: -240px;
    left: 0;
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<a id="concurso" href="">
  <img id="concurso1" src="/images/consurso_de_disfraces_carnival_2013_rojo_inico.png" alt="Concurso de Disfraces Lira in Wonderland 2013" />
  <img id="concurso2" src="/images/consurso_de_disfraces_carnival_2013_rosa_inico.png" alt="Concurso de Disfraces Lira in Wonderland 2013" />
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you just run the code, you'll see an error

```
$('#concurso2').fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
```

try running it on http://lirainwonderland.es/

this means you have different version on your 2 pages

```
jQuery.fn.jquery; // checks jQuery version
```

but then that's not the problem, it seems your $() is not jQuery, maybe you have other script like mootools, prototype, etc there

instead of $, you could use **jQuery** and it worked when I tried it.

```
jQuery('#concurso2').fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
```

Comment: That is the code I'm running on lirainwonderland.es, doesn't seem to work. I just coppied and pasted the code from tienda.lirainwonderland.es that works.

Comment: in the console log, are you using chrome or firefox?

Comment: Looks like jQuery is included twice on http://lirainwonderland.es (1.7.1 and 1.7.2)

Comment: yep, looks like it was loaded twice. @ExplicitBrandDesign, you might want to move your codes after the /wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.7.2 (since this came from WordPress already) and remove your 1.7.1

Comment: using jQuery(selector) worked for me, although I didn't see any errors pop up in the consol log after checking before adjusting the code. The code on this site has got a bit messy and I will have to clean it up another day. Thanks a bunch fedmich!

Comment: Cool. You might want to read about minifying javascripts, also all those scripts can be combined into 1 js file.
But that is another story, another day :)

Comment: Looks like there was an included PHP file including jquery the 2nd time, after removing it, now I can use $(selector) as usual.